# posting values with select

Tags: php, post

I'm having some trouble here when I try to get the value from my  using

I'm doing this in a dinamic way because the number of values which are shown can be different.

After submiting ($_POST) I'm getting "Undefined index: country" when I use `$query = "SELECT id FROM country WHERE country.name = '" . $_POST['country'] . "'";`

I already checked $_POST with var_dump() and this is the only value that is not being sent. What should I do?

Here is the  code, thanks in advance.

```
<select required="">
     <?php for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) { ?>
        <option name="country" value="<?php echo $country_name[$x]->name ?>">
            <?php echo $country_name[$x]->name ?>
         </option>               
      <?php} ?>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
<select name="country">
     <?php for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) { ?>
        <option  value="<?php echo $country_name[$x]->name ?>">
            <?php echo $country_name[$x]->name ?>
         </option>               
      <?php} ?>
 </select>
```